# Per-site-meta questions not showing up on network profile Top Questions

Tags: bug, per-site-meta, network-profile

I was looking at [Jin's network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/21721/jin) to find his posts on each pre-graduation meta site about the design choices. However, his Top Questions section includes no meta posts. His activity tab showed some meta activity, but I believe that may also be incomplete.

Where can I access his top Meta posts?

Comment: Nooooo! [My Meta TeX bug report!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4274/35325)